# How to make CSS animation use the applied style from previous animation

Tags: css, css-animations

I am making a checkbox thing, and I have an animation when going from unchecked to checked.

I have set the `animation-fill-mode: forwards` so that the css state is applied after the first animation which is initialized on check. How can i get the next animation to go from that state. Currently it reads what is specified in the css file which is the initial state, not the one applied from the first animation. Also if I set `from { ... }` on the second animation that animation (meant to be played on checked to unchecked) plays on page load because it plays on unchecked which is the initial state.

```
input[type="checkbox"] {
    display: none;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked + .outer_checkbox  {     
    -webkit-animation-name: checked_color;       
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked + .outer_checkbox > .inner_checkbox {
    -webkit-animation-name: checked_placement;      
}

.inner_checkbox, .outer_checkbox {
    border: 1px solid black;
   -webkit-animation-duration: 0.3s;
   -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.outer_checkbox {
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 32px;
    height: 16px;

    border-radius: 8px;     
    background-color: grey;

    -webkit-animation-name: unchecked_color;

}

.inner_checkbox {
    width: 18px;
    height: 18px;
    border-radius: 9px;   
    margin: -2px;     
    background-color: white;

    -webkit-animation-name: unchecked_placement;       
}

@-webkit-keyframes checked_color {
    to {
        background-color: green;
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes checked_placement {  
    to {
        margin-left: 14px;
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes unchecked_color {
    to {
        background-color: grey;
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes unchecked_placement {  
    to {
        margin-left: -2px;
    }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/sg86n25L/1/

Comment: For that case, I would not use animation keyframes. Instead, I would use css animations applied on properties (margin-left & background-color) -> http://jsfiddle.net/piiantom/qrz95mk2/

Comment: @PIIANTOM You mean transitions  ...  But you are right, it's the way to go